# Wrap an element in MooTools with custom class

Tags: javascript, oop, mootools

In MooTools, is it possible to do the following:

```
var MyClass = new Class({
    initialize: function (el) {
        this.element = document.id(el);
    }
});

console.log( instanceOf(document.id('test-div'), Element ); // Logs: 'true'

var instance = new MyClass('test-div');
console.log( instanceOf(instance, MyClass );                 // expected result: 'true'
console.log( instanceOf(document.id('test-div'), MyClass );  // expected result: 'true'
```

In other words, if my class has been instantiated on an element, it should return "MyClass" instead of "Element"

Comment: not really. `document.id` is a selector and it's meant to traverse DOM and return an element (or lack thereof) in the fastest possible way. it also extends non-extended elements for IE and sets up element storage. it will always return an `Element` type (or `null`). nothing can magically tell if you have an instance anywhere that has a reference to the element. you can write your own wiring for this kind of behaviour - but there may be other patterns here. like prop getters/setters - https://github.com/DimitarChristoff/mailcheck/blob/master/Source/mailcheck.js#L151-L167 etc.

Comment: depends what you are trying to do / what goals.

Comment: Well my original intention was to create a wrapper around an element with my own methods exposed - similar to how jQuery works - however if this isn't possible it looks like extending the element with getter/setters is the only way to go.

Comment: you can create it - you can also extend the Element prototype. it's very flexible - but what is your goal, though. what problem do you solve with the above or the wrapper around `document.id` - having a contextual element? you can use `toElement` in a class - http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element so `document.id(instance)` will return `this.element` when `toElement: function(){ return this.element; }` - see http://jsfiddle.net/w00fz/uUxDm/light/

Comment: This "http://jsfiddle.net/uUxDm/35/" is what I wanted to do, where as this "http://jsfiddle.net/uUxDm/36/" does what I want it to do.